# ASP.NET MVC JQuery closest HiddenFor val

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have table:

```
  <table class="table table-bordered">
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td width="25px">
                    @if (!Model[i].Letter.Equals(letter))
                    {
                        @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => Model[i].Letter);

                    }
                </td>
                <td width="45px">
                    <div class="button-edit"></div>

                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Student.Id, new { @class = "mojaklasa" } )

                </td>

                <td>
                    ...
                </td>
                <td>
                  ...
                </td>
                <td>
                   ...
                </td>
            </tr>

        }
    </table>
```

And how can i get closest hiddenfor value to button?
i tried:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.button-edit').each(function () {
                $(this).mouseenter(function () {
                    $(this).fadeTo(20, 1).css('cursor', 'pointer');
                });
                $(this).mouseleave(function () {
                    $(this).fadeTo(20, 0.5);
                });
                $(this).click(function () {

                    var id;
                    $(this).closest('.mojaklasa').val(id);
                    alert(id);

                });
            });
```

and with $(this).next....
Still if i click this button i dont have anything in alert box. 
I have even put class inside  but i can get this text from it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the parent tr and then try to find the input.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.button-edit').each(function () {
            $(this).mouseenter(function () {
                $(this).fadeTo(20, 1).css('cursor', 'pointer');
            });
            $(this).mouseleave(function () {
                $(this).fadeTo(20, 0.5);
            });
            $(this).click(function () {
                var id;
                $(this).closest("tr").find('.mojaklasa').val(id);
                alert(id);

            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.mojaklasa').val(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a search relative to a parent of the item clicked, but you should never connect multiple events in an `each`. That is pointless as jQuery manages the multiple handler for you.

```
$(function () {
    $('.button-edit').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(20, 1).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(20, 0.5);
    }).click(function () {
        var id = $(this).closest("tr").find('.mojaklasa').val();
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

This will connect the 3 handlers to *all* elements with class `.button-edit`. You also needed to use the value returned from `val()` and not call `val` with a parameter (as that sets the hidden value).